# Paradoxical issue while checking the proof of a simple relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm trying to run a double check on a proof I did while working on some equations of a paper and I run into something that can't be right.

Specifically, I used equation,

$\sqrt{1-\frac{2m_{-}}{r}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{2m_{+}}{r}}=4\pi\sigma r$

to prove that after squaring twice gives us,

$m_{s}^{2}+4m_{+}m_{-}=[\frac{m_{s}^{2}}{2r}+m_{+}+m_{-}]^{2}$

where $m_{-}$, $m_{+}$ are constants and $m_{s}$ is given by,

$m_{s}=4\pi\sigma r^{2}$

That was easy enough, and my results are verified by the paper. But something weird happens when I solve the first equation for $\sigma$ and substitute the result inside the second one. Instead of the complete elimination of all terms, one would expect, I get a sextic with respect to $r$.

How is this possible? Is there something I'm missing, or perhaps a mistake in my logic? I would appreciate any suggestion.

P.S. I used a simple Mathematica script for the last part's calculations (the substitution) and that's what produced the sextic.

Comment: You probably introduced spurious solutions with your substitutions. Try factoring the polynomial and see if you get the original as one of the factors.

Comment: @probably_someone Factoring doesn't produce the original. Do you mean that when I squared the initial equation twice I introduced other solutions to my system? Wouldn't substituting the original still solve it? It's like having y=x -> y^4 = x^4, the substitution of x in the place of y still gives us elimination regardless of the spurious solutions inducted....